# WPF / XAML VisualStateManager Who handles event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my CustomControl I am using a VisualStateManager like this:

```
...
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="toggleRegionContent"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                         From="0"
                                         To="{TemplateBinding ContentHeight}"
                                         Duration="0:0:.7" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrowIcon"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                         From="0"
                                         To="180"
                                         Duration="0:0:.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                <VisualState>
                <!-- Some other States -->
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager>
    <ToggleButton>
<!-- The Rest of the Control -->
```

My Question now is how the Event Checked is handled or who handles it. Does the VisualStateManager automatically Switch the State when the ToggleButton is clicked. Or do i have to give my ToggleButton a Checked Event and assign the State of the Button in the Code Behind with something like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(Control, "Checked", true);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or do i have to give my ToggleButton a Checked Event and assign the State of the Button in the Code Behind with something like this:

Yes, your custom control is responsible for setting the current visual state of the control using the `VisualStateManager` class and its `GoToState` method.

You can read more about this on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The Code Behind way Looks pretty clean. At this Point i want to ask you if you can tell me which way is the cleaner one: Code Behind or pure XAML (The answer of WBuck)

Comment: You need both. The VisualStates are defined in the XAML markup of the ControlTemplate and you call the VisualStateManager.GoToState method programmatically in the control class to determine in which state the control currently is. The animations that you have defined in the XAML gets applied when the GoToState method is called for that particular state.

Comment: I tried the Solution of WBuck and it works perfectly, without any Code Behind. That's why i ask if Code Behind is the cleaner Solution in this Scenario or if the Interaction Triggers are better. My XAML/Wpf Knowledge isn't high enough for this Kind of Question.

Comment: Calling the VisualStateManager.GoToState  is both cleaner and more flexible in my opinion. If you want to do everything in XAML you might as well use triggers instead of visual states.

Comment: The GoToState method is the better choice for a custom control. You're directly interacting with the xaml from the control class so it probably makes more sense to do it the way mm8 provided. If, on the other hand, you're making a mvvm application and you want minimal to no code in the code behind then go with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to switch the state by using either the GoToStateAction behavior or the DataStateBehavior.

The DataStateBehavior is nice if you're only switching between 2 states.
The GoToStateAction is nice if you want to switch between multiple states.

First, here is a very simple example using the DataStateBehavior. I switch the color of the rectangle on a checkbox click.

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"
                                  To="Checked">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"
                                  To="Unchecked">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="myRect">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="#FF6F6FFF" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckBox}"
                              Value="True"
                              TrueState="Checked"
                              FalseState="Unchecked" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Rectangle x:Name="myRect"
               Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="43.166,74.07,0,153.968"
               Stroke="Black"
               Width="104.438" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"
              Content="CheckBox"
              Height="20.776"
              Margin="239.69,88.668,192.524,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" />

</Grid>
```

And here is an example using GoToStateAction. Again i'm just changing the rectangle color based on a checkbox being checked.

```
    <Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"
                                  To="Checked">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"
                                  To="Unchecked">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetName="myRect">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                             Value="#FF6F6FFF" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="myRect"
               Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="43.166,74.07,0,153.968"
               Stroke="Black"
               Width="104.438" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"
              Content="CheckBox"
              Height="20.776"
              Margin="239.69,88.668,192.524,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckBox}"
                            Value="True">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Checked" />
            </ei:DataTrigger>
            <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckBox}"
                            Value="False">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Unchecked" />
            </ei:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </CheckBox>

</Grid>
```

EDIT:
Ensure you add a reference to the Blend SDK for the above methods to work.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Comment: Thanks for the Long answer and the Code Snippet. But im not sure if the XAML Answer is cleaner than the Code Behind Solution.

Comment: Your answer works too, but in my Opinion the answer which mm8 provided looks cleaner. But thanks for this solution. It helped in understanding the VisualStateManager.